# Counting circular and square stars in numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, data-science, logistic-regression

**SOLVED** (by @AaronKeesing)
If the goal is to predict numeric values, linear regression should be applied. But instead I went with logistic regression for binary classification.

The exercise is stated as follows:

- Given the data 'stars_train_X_y.npz'. I need to found out a model that can predict whether there are   more circular stars than square stars and return a 1 if there are more circular stars and a 0 otherwise.
- I must use a linear or logistic regression model to fit the train data.
- accuracy_score has to be higher than 0.9

My approach:
I predict the number of circular and square stars and compare the two lists, but I only get an accuracy_score of 0.715.

```py
import sklearn
import sklearn.linear_model
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score


import numpy as np

data = np.load('stars_train_X_y.npz')
X = data['X_train'] #   np.ndarray of size (8000, 4096),  flattened image (64x64) of the night sky.
y = data['y_train'] #   np.ndarray of size (8000, 2), number of circular stars and number square stars

#Split dataset into 80% trian, 10% test, 10# val
(X_train, X_temp, y_train, y_temp) = train_test_split(data['X_train'], data['y_train'], test_size=0.2, random_state=0, shuffle = True)
(X_test, X_val, y_test, y_val) = train_test_split(X_temp, y_temp, test_size=0.5, random_state=0, shuffle = True)

#Getting list of either number of circular stars and square stars
def shapeList(inp, elm):
    n = [(t[elm]) for t in inp]
    return n 

cLstTrain = shapeList(y_train, 0) # y_train: only circular stars count
cLstTest = shapeList(y_test, 0)   # y_test: only circular stars count
sLstTrain = shapeList(y_train, 1) # y_train: only square stars count
sLstTest = shapeList(y_test, 1)   # y_test: only square stars count

def predict(trainX_, trainY_, testX_, testY_ ):
    model = sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression(random_state=0, max_iter=1000)
    model.fit(trainX_, trainY_)
    pred = model.predict(testX_)
    MSE = mean_squared_error(testY_, pred)
    ACC = accuracy_score(testY_, pred)
    print("MSE : " + str(MSE))
    print("ACC : " + str(ACC) )
    return pred

circularPredictions = (predict(X_train, cLstTrain, X_test, cLstTest))
squarePredictions = (predict(X_train, sLstTrain, X_test, sLstTest))

'''1 for pictures with more stars, 0 for pictures with less stars. (compared with square stars)'''
def compare(CircPred, SqrePred):
    lst = []
    for i in range (0, len(CircPred)):
        if CircPred[i] > SqrePred[i]: 
            n = 1
            lst.append([n])
        else:
            n = 0
            lst.append([n])
    return lst

predictions = (compare(circularPredictions, squarePredictions))
testValues = (compare(cLstTest, sLstTest))
print(accuracy_score(testValues, predictions))
```

To improve the accuracy I have tried the following:

**Grid search**

I used:

```
paramGrid = {
    'penalty': ['l1', 'l2'],
    'C': [0.1, 1, 10, 100]
}
model_search = GridSearchCV(model, paramGrid, cv=5)
```

This gave me a slightly better accuracy of 0.72, but runtime increased from 2 min to 18 min.

I'm pretty certain that the solution is preprocessing for this I have tried the following techniques:

- MinMaxScaler: resulted in reduced accuracy
- Binarizer : resulted in reduced accuracy
- PowerTransformer : resulted in reduced accuracy

I'm very new at these sorts of things, what kind of preprocessing techniques can you suggests or is there maybe another way to make improvements?

Thanks in advance :D

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You're using logistic regression to do numeric prediction. You should use linear regression for numeric prediction, or logistic regression for binary classification. Have you tried a binary classifier to directly predict which is higher?

Comment: @AaronKeesing Thank you, binary classification works.